# How to remove a character in a variable of string type in R

Tags: r

Hi dear I have a variable of this type in R:

```
v1
CAR10100231095000C 
CAR10100231189000 
CAR10100231191000C 
CAR10100231192000 
CAR10100231194000C 
CAR101002311950002 
CAR101002311960001
```

My problem is with rows that have a `C` as last element of the observation. I was trying to use `nchar()` function but I have others rows that have the same length for example `CAR10100231191000C`and CAR101002311960001. My problem is how to remove `C` from raws with this character and get a new variable of this form:

```
v1
CAR10100231095000 
CAR10100231189000 
CAR10100231191000 
CAR10100231192000 
CAR10100231194000 
CAR101002311950002 
CAR101002311960001
```

Where `Cs` were removed from rows that have and the rest of the rows have their original form. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `sub` for this:

```
sub('C$', '', v1)
```

Which removes the letter `C` from the last position in the string if it exists.